# How to rollback all transaction statements from handler when one of them throws an error?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, handler

I have the following SQL stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK; 
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES (55556666);
        DROP TABLE xaxa;
    ROLLBACK; 
END
```

The `DROP TABLE xaxa;` statement throws an error because such DB does not exist, however, the INSERT statement is executed and in phpmyadmin I can see the inserted user.
However, if I remove the troublesome statement `DROP TABLE xaxa;` the INSERT
is rolled back.
Can someone help me rollback the insert from the handler if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DROP TABLE statement can't be rolled back and it causes an implicit commit.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html